# Returning json result in function

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting json response from ajax request

I want to return json result to getTwitterVal() function call in var `obj`. And then getting name and id in `$('#loginTwitter').click(function data() {}`. How to this this?

Following code returns alert 'undefined'

```
function getTwitterVal()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //result looks like this : {"name": jack,"id":1}
            //obj = JSON.parse(result);

            return result;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","redirect.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
    // api_call();
}

$('#loginTwitter').click(function data() {

    var obj = getTwitterVal();
    alert(obj.name);                    // I want retrieve name and id both value here
 }
```

**UPDATED code**

```
function getTwitterVal(clb)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                clb(obj);
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","redirect.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
    // api_call();
}



$('#loginTwitter').click(function data() {
    getTwitterVal(function(obj) {
        alert(obj.name);
    });
});
```

Gives error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character var obj = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: `getTwitterVal` doesn't return anything - and it *can't* return any meaningful JSON because the XHR request is *asynchronous* meaning it *doesn't complete* by the time the `getTwitterVal` function ends. You'll need to use a *callback* or *promises* which are invoked/resolved in the "complete" handler of the XHR onreadystatechange.

Comment: responses in ajax call is available inside ajax method only. It will not be accessible outside. That's why you are getting `undefined`. Use `callback `

Comment: @ShijuKBabu: can you please check udated code

Comment: @user2864740: can you please check updated code

Comment: Does this question owe upvote : ) ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. AJAX call is asynchronous. Although it is possible to make it synchronous you should never do it (since it will block all other scripts on the page). Instead pass a callback to `getTwitterVal`:

```
function getTwitterVal(clb) {
    // some code
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                clb(obj);
            }
    // other code
}
```

and then

```
$('#loginTwitter').click(function data() {
    getTwitterVal(function(obj) {
        alert(obj.name);
    });
}
```

Comment: @freaksih: thanks, but it gives `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

var obj = JSON.parse(result);` error

Comment: @Programming_crazy Check if `result` is a valid JSON - it probably isn't.

Comment: @Programming_crazy freakish is correct... you almost certainly have invalid JSON... put a console.log(result); and check the source you have received.

Comment: @freakish: one issue. It works in FF fine but when I tested in chrome it gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < login.php:101
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange login.php:101` any idea about this?

Comment: @deadlyDev: can you please see this new issue

Comment: @Programming_crazy That's the same error - you are trying to parse an invalid JSON. Check `xmlhttp.responseText` one more time before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchronous ajax, as mentioned by @freakish. Also, if you already use jquery, then let it makes its ajax work also. Something like that:

```
$('#loginTwitter').click(function() {
    $.post(
        'redirect.php',
        function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(obj.name);
        });
});
```

Comment: i tried this but it does not seem to work. gives `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

var obj = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: I missed one bracket :) please try again. And also please check that server returns valid JSON.